# IOS9. Is it possible to disable 3D touch in app?

Tags: ios, ios9, 3dtouch

Is it possible to remove the `3D Touch` in my application through code or settings in my application? In my application, for iPhone 6s/6s+ click, touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded events are not working correctly. How to find out the cause without buying new devices?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean to disable 3D touch by saying “Remove 3D Touch in my Application”, following is the explanation.

There are two main types of 3D touch actions

1. Home Screen Quick Actions.
2. Peek and Pop

You can check and implement the delegate methods to change the implementation of 3D touch for the above scenarios, refer to the Apple’s documentation
[3D Touch APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/3DTouchAPIs.html)

touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded is nothing to do with 3D Touch.

Comment: It seems I don't fully understand 3D Touch. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: With 3d touch pressure changes cause `touchesMoved` to be called, so apps that assume `touchesMoved` corresponds only to coordinate changes will break. I wouldn't say it "has nothing to do with 3D Touch".

Comment: Running into a problem with 3D Touch here and it goes beyond Quick actions and Peek and Pop. There's also the Fast App Switcher that you can bring up with a long-ish press on the left side of the screen, followed by a right swipe. The problem is that the Os is eating the begin touches while it waits for the gesture. It affects every app, including Settings...

Comment: This is exactly the problem we're seeing. It only sends touch began when you let go. Does anyone know how to just switch it off in code, for example when your app has focus, so the OS doesn't behave as mentioned here, and "eat" the touches ?

Comment: @ADB I am facing the same problem how do I disable Fast App Switcher in my app ?? anyone ?

Comment: @Netero I haven't heard of any solution to the problem so far